# How to create a new row in Table A while also creating a new Row in Table B with the ID from Table A

Tags: .net, entity-framework, razor-pages

Jobs table has a PK/FK 1-1 relationship with JobDates table.
How do I change my Create Job post call to also generate a new row for the JobDates table with the JobID (unknown during submit as it doesn't exist yet)

```
public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnPost() 
{

    var Job = new Job()
    {
        JobNum = AddJobRequest.JobNum,
        CustomerId = AddJobRequest.CustomerId,
        JobName = AddJobRequest.JobName,
        JobDescription = AddJobRequest.JobDescription,
        JobType = AddJobRequest.JobType,
        JobStatusId = AddJobRequest.JobStatus,
        JobPM = AddJobRequest.JobPM,
        JobSM = AddJobRequest.JobSM,
        JobQty = AddJobRequest.JobQty
    };
    _context.Jobs.Add(Job);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    CustomerList = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    return new RedirectToPageResult("/Index");
    
}
```

I've looked all over for other examples and maybe I'm not wording things correctly to find the answers. I feel like this has to be pretty routine.

Comment: how is your DbContext, have you override the OnModelCreating to ensure the HasRequired. and HasForeingKey ? Please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
public async Task<RedirectToPageResult> OnPost() 
{

    var Job = new Job()
    {
        JobNum = AddJobRequest.JobNum,
        CustomerId = AddJobRequest.CustomerId,
        JobName = AddJobRequest.JobName,
        JobDescription = AddJobRequest.JobDescription,
        JobType = AddJobRequest.JobType,
        JobStatusId = AddJobRequest.JobStatus,
        JobPM = AddJobRequest.JobPM,
        JobSM = AddJobRequest.JobSM,
        JobQty = AddJobRequest.JobQty,
        JobDate = new JobDate()
    };
    _context.Jobs.Add(Job);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    CustomerList = await _context.Customers.ToListAsync();
    return new RedirectToPageResult("/Index");
    
}
```